# Java Range find difference between largest and smallest int

Tags: java

I'm having trouble figuring out how exactly to make it find the max number and minimum number in the array.

Write a method range that accepts an ArrayList of integers as a parameter and that returns the range of values contained in the list, which is defined as 1 more than the difference between the largest and smallest elements. For example if a variable called list stores the following values:

[18, 14, 29, 12, 7, 25]

The call of range(list) should return 23, because this is one more than the largest difference between any pair of values (29 - 7 + 1 = 23). An empty list is defined to have a range of 0.

So far I have this:

```
public static int range(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int range = 0;
  for (int i: list)
    {
       if (list.size() > 0)
        {
         range = max - min + 1;
        }
    }
      return range;
}
```

Thank you VERY MUCH!

Comment: Hint `Math.max` and `Math.min` will help

Comment: You should calculate min anx max within the loop and return the difference after the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have more than method to achive this goal.

Using Collections (more compact but expensive because it iterates two times on the list, one to find the max and one to find the min):

```
public static int range(final ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (Collections.max(list) - Collections.min(list)) + 1;
    }
}
```

Or using your own algorithm like this (more code but finds min and max with just one loop):

```
public static int range(final ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int max = list.get(0);
        int min = list.get(0);
        for (final int i : list) {
            if (i > max) {
                max = i;
            } else if (i < min) {
                min = i;
            }
        }
        return (max - min) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cld use Math.min and Math.max instead

Comment: No, i can't because:
"The method max(int, int) in the type Math is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Integer>)"

Comment: `Using Collections (more compact but expensive because it iterates two times on the list)` Does it?

Comment: Yes, it does. The ArrayList doens't compute the max or the min of the list when you add or remove an element. Therefore Collections.max iteterates one time on the list and Collections.min another one.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [Collections.min](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection%29) and [Collections.max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
int difference = Collections.max(list) - Collections.min(list);
```

Comment: Why "subclass"? Just return the calculation

Comment: +1 I have been bested in the "less code" paradigm :) @mad Now *that's* cheating!

Comment: This code can throw a NoSuchElementException if the list is empty. You must check it before calling the max and min methods.

Answer (score 2):

You never calculate the max and the min value in your loop.

Hint : In this loop, find the max and the min value. Then calculate the range and return it.

```
int min = 0;
int max = 0;
for (int i: list){
 //find max and min here
}
return max - min + 1;
```

Comment: This fails when the list contains negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This task only needs two lines:

```
Collections.sort(list);
return list.isEmpty() ? 0 : list.get(list.size() - 1) - list.get(0);
```

- Use the java JDK's API to do the heavy lifting for you
- It's how you look at a problem that's important
- Less code is good (as long as it's legible

Comment: This code can throw a NoSuchElementException if the list is empty. You must check it before calling the max and min methods.

Comment: @LucaMastrostefano yes - this isn't a complete, safe solution, but as you have raised this point I've added safety. Still only two lines :)

Comment: Now is great! But in my opinion sorting is a waste of resource, is better using min and max methods.

Comment: @LucaMastrostefano the difference in performance would be measured in microseconds, possibly nanoseconds. Actually this could be not much slower than max/min, because max/min requires two traversal s of the list - If the list is sort enough, sorting would be very fast.

Comment: How can you know how the objects are compared? Try to sort million of objects with a very expensive method. You could lose seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort it and then peek fist and last item.

```
public static int range(List<Integer> input)
{
     if(input == null || input.size() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("");

     if(input.size() == 1) return 0;

     List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList(input);

     Collections.sort(copy);

     int min = copy.get(0);
     int max = copy.get(copy.lenght-1);

     return max - min; 
}
```

This is not a perfect solution as list may contain nulls.

You can start with simple comparison.

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for(Integer integer : input) {
   if(i == null) continue;

   int i = integer.intValue();

   if(i < min) {
     min = i;
   } 

   if(i > max) {
    max = i;
   } 
}

return max - min;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int range(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    int min = list.get(0);
    int max = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if (list.get(i) > max)
            max = list.get(i);
        if ((list.get(i) < min))
            min = list.get(i);
    }
    return max-min+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution that works. Let me explain how it works.

The first if statement checks for the empty list case.

Afterwards, I declared an integer variable `int diff` to return at the end. Two numbers are selected by the two for loops where the first one starts at index `0` while the nested loop starts at index `1` so that no same numbers are considered when looping through. The difference between two numbers are obtained using the formula declared as `int calc`. Since we're looking for the biggest difference between two numbers, we set `diff = calc` and keep it updating.

Lastly, we return `diff + 1` as the problem stated.

```
public int range(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    if (list.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int diff = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            int calc = Math.abs(list.get(i) - list.get(j));
            if (diff < calc) {
                diff = calc;
            }
        }
    }
    return diff + 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is nearly 8 years old) with existing answers.